# How to style a single wordpress widget

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using a newsletter plugin in http://coconutwaterblog.com. But i want to style that single widget with heading background as yellow.
Can anyone suggest me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: what about overwriting css? on what exact page you have the newsletter plugin?

Comment: on the wordpress sidebar

Comment: really need a yellow background because we don't see it...

Comment: I want overwrite css to do that

Comment: ok found it..the id of li element is `newsletterwidget-2` and the class is `omc-widget widget_newsletterwidget`. Add the id or class to your css and try with `background-color`

Comment: the heading you get with `#newsletterwidget-2 h3{background:yellow;}`

Comment: but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the widget is developed, it could be pushing the styles inline and not via CSS.

Use Developer Tools (such as Firebug) to determine where the current styles are coming from to determine where they need to be altered to achieve the desired result.

If able, you could then alter the theme style sheet to include what you wanted to do to the specified element.

After viewing your site, I had problems determing which widget you were attempting to alter.  If ti's the "FROM THE BLOG" widget, the CSS would appear as such:

```
#omc-sidebar.omc-right ul.xoxo li#pages-2.omc-widget h3.widgettitle {background:yellow;}
```

And, after looking at the markup on the page, it appears those attributes come in to play on line 80 of the document itself, which means you're not going to be able to over-ride them with a style sheet.  You will have to alter the code either in the plugin of the theme itself.